# Meaning of java error "SNO: '+=' reconversion failed"?

Tags: java, hashmap, kettle, pdi, janino

I encountered a mysterious error in Pentaho Data Integration (PDI, a.k.a. Kettle) log displayed via Jenkins:

> org.codehaus.janino.CompileException: SNO: "+=" reconversion failed

The only code that contains "+=" is like this...

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
private static final String validKeys = "thing zero,thing two";
private Map/*<String, Long>*/ mapCount;

public boolean init ... {
    mapCount = new HashMap/*<String, Long>*/();
}
public boolean processRow ... {
    mapCount.put("thing zero", 0L);
    mapCount.put("thing one", 1L);
    Long calcUnidentified = 0L;
    Long calcTotal = 0L;
    Iterator it = mapCount.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry keyValuePair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        
        String currentKey = keyValuePair.getKey().toString();
        Long currentValue = Long.valueOf(keyValuePair.getValue().toString());
        
        if (!validKeys.contains(currentKey)) {
            calcUnidentified += currentValue;
        }
        calcTotal += currentValue;
    }
}
```

### I tried:

- googled/ecosia for the error message
- searched stack overflow for the error message: nothing
- searched stack overflow for the individual concepts: each seems fine afaik
- looked up the details such as compatible types and return types for Long.valueOf, +=, and HashMap's .put, .getKey, .getValue
- tested the parts of that code in w3schools online java tester
- replaced `public boolean processRow` with their usual `public static void main`
- this code doesn't error in w3schools but goes blank until I replace it so much that really I'm just testing the components.
- whereas Janine seems to dislike the alternative, iterating with a colon in a for a loop -- expected semicolon.

Comment: Did you try using a different compiler rather than janino? Did you try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and report a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message? "The only code that contains "+=" is like this..." Okay, but what is the code that you *need to include, in order to cause the error*?

Comment: Did you try declaring `calcUnidentified` and `calcTotal` as `long` instead of `Long`? To me it seems these variables do always have a value and therefore declaring them as `Long` seems wrong.

Comment: Karl, janino is my only option. the portions i could test outside janino, including += functionality in general, do work elsewhere. If you believe this is a janino-specific problem and solution then maybe I should change the title to include "janino" in the question title? Also, I confirmed that code is what one needs to include, in order to cause the error.

Comment: Thomas, I tried long and Long outside of janino and they both worked. I could try long in janino too, now that Karl mentioned the compiler.

Comment: The compile error is a `janino.CompileException` so it seems very janino-specific, and if you search for "janino sno reconversion" you find [this place](https://github.com/janino-compiler/janino/blob/master/janino/src/main/java/org/codehaus/janino/UnitCompiler.java#L4832) where it is thrown. Seems to be a bug in janino.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas! It really took me by surprise that it could actually be += itself that doesn't work here. I assumed it was something around it that I had done wrong! All it took was that realization and `calcUnidentified = calcUnidentified + currentValue;` to fix this. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As strange as it may sound for java, the solution was to simply replace...

```
calcUnidentified += currentValue;
```

...with...

```
calcUnidentified = calcUnidentified + currentValue;
```

As Thomas Kläger noted, this bug seems very specific to Janino (used by PDI for java).